# Web Python instead of addslashes

Tags: php, python, sql-injection

i am familiar with php. but new to python. in php i will use addslashes() and stripslashes() method. instead of this what solution is there in python for avoiding sql conflicts.

Comment: First, you shouldn't be doing that in PHP.  Second, there's nothing **directly** like that in Python.  You shouldn't do that in Python, either.  You might want to expand on your question to show the SQL you think you're going to do.  You also might want to read up on the Python DB-API.

Comment: You should **never** use `addslashes()` to prevent SQL injection but - if you cannot use PDO prepared statements or something like `pg_exec_params()` - the DB-specific method, e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string()` for MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is parameterized statements, where you will do something like this:

```
db.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:user;', {'user': 'john'})
```

Your SQL client library will handle the quoting and escaping for you. The exact details depend on the library you use (for example, if your RDBMS is PostgreSQL, the library could be psycopg2).

Comment: Personally I prefer the `%s` placeholders and a tuple instead of a dict for the arguments. Especailly for queries with few arguments that's much less to write and not less readable.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - keep in mind that the [`%`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101) operator is deprecated.  Prefer [`"".format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples) for forward compatibility.

Comment: @Nate: It's not used as an operator. That would allow SQL injection. It's used like this: `db.execute('SELECT ... WHERE col = %s', (something, ))`

Comment: @Nate: actually, if you would use the % operator, you still would have the injection problem as well.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I misunderstood.  I saw `%s` and jumped to conclusions.